# Convert Azure AppInsights `timestamp` into `datetime`

Tags: azure, datetime, timestamp, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer

I'm trying to solve the simplest of problems...

How do I convert a `timestamp` into a `datetime`?

Comment: You haven't found any post related to that ? Which programming language?

Comment: it might be helpful if you provide an example, for instance how would you like to convert the timestamp `17.23:01:02.2233445` into a `datetime` value?

Comment: Azure App Insights - inside the Azure Portal? @Thomas what do you mean "Language"?

Comment: What did  mean convert to a datetime? You want change the format or change anything else you want? Or did you just want it shown as the local time(not utc)?

Comment: Could you provide any example? So we could understand your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in which language you are trying, but below is solution with SQL.

select CONVERT(DATETIME,convert(DATETIMEoffset,'2019-07-29T08:05:09.7320868Z'))